# XMLReader - Как обработать ошибку?

Tags: php, xmlreader

При умышленном искажении файла XML (удаляю один тег)  получаю предупреждение

`Warning: XMLReader::expand():`

`Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMDocument::importNode() must be an instance of DOMNode,`

Как правильно можно обработать данную ошибку и другие возможные ?

```
function openXML($file_name,$key,$limit=0){

    $z = new XMLReader;
    $z->open($file_name);
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    $result = array();
    
    while ($z->read() && $z->name !== $key);
    
    $i = 0;
    while ($z->name === $key)
    {
        
        $fdfsd = $z->expand();
        $df = $doc->importNode($fdfsd, true);
        $node = simplexml_import_dom($df);      
        
        $i++;
        $z->next($key);
        
        $result[]=$node;
        
        if($limit>0 && $i==$limit)
            break;
        

    }

    
    return $result;
    
}
```

Comment: вы разберитесь, что вам возвращает `expand` и как это соотносится с тем, что на вход просит `importNode`

Comment: @teran хотелось бы получить более точный ответ с примером

Comment: так это и не ответ был. ошибка вам говорит, что на вход указанной функции требуется экземпляр `DOMNode`. Вот и прочтите в документации, что возвращает `expand`. Тут вариантов то всего два. Либо он в принципе возвращает не этот класс/интерфейс, либо вернул NULL.